# Why does Postman complain about an expired certificate even though expiration date is in future

Tags: https, postman, ssl-certificate, tls1.3

Using Postman I access 2 different URLs that belong to the same domain:

- A: https://www.example.com
- B: https://other.example.com

`A` responds fine, but `B` responds with `Warning: Certificate has expired`. I am wondering why that is so?

Both `A` and `B` respond with same certifacate which expires in 2 months.

[image]

Subject looks like this:

```
commonName: "example.com"
alternativeNames: "DNS:example.com, DNS:*.example.com"
```

Comment: They are both the same certificate. Perhaps there is a subject name conflict.

Comment: I have just updated the OP with the details on subject